# Flipping fields in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a document that looks like this for instance:

```
{
    "a" : "val",
    "b" : "another val"
}
```

How can I flip specified fields so that the result looks like

```
{
    "b" : "val",
    "a" : "another val"
}
```

I've tried `db.collection.update({}, {$rename:{'a':'b', 'b':'a'}})` but I get the error `Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic coin shuffle problem. Probably what you are missing in the above is that you are allways going to collide with having the same `field` specified when trying to form this update in 1 step. You will have to do it in multiple steps, so logically:

```
db.collection.update({}, {$rename: { 'a': 'c' }})
db.collection.update({}, {$rename: { 'b': 'a' }})
db.collection.update({}, {$rename: { 'c': 'b' }})
```

But we can do better and avoid the collision in two steps

```
db.collection.update({}, {$rename:{ 'a': 'c', 'b': 'd' }})
db.collection.update({}, {$rename:{ 'c': 'b', 'd': 'a' }})
```

Of course this is not one operation and it's not easy and **no** you cannot reference the value of another field and update it to another.

And of course, only do this where you **really** need to change your field names. The [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) manual page covers the use cases. If you **just** want to **see** things that way, simply [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the form you want:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([{$project: { a: "$b", b: "$a" }}])
```

Answer (score -1):

It is worth noting that with the new bulk update operations coming in MongoDB 2.6 it is possible to do this rename in a single server-side operation. As of the time of this posting 2.6 is still in pre-relase; you can check the [MongoDB download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) for availability. Check the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/) for a complete list of changes and new features.

Here is the mongo shell syntax for doing this field rename in a single server-side command:

```
var bulk = db.c.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({}).update({$rename: {a:'tmp'}})
bulk.find({}).update({$rename: {b:'a'}})
bulk.find({}).update({$rename: {tmp:'b'}})
bulk.execute()
```

Comment: Can't see how this helps this question. It is a single document update as was specified. Maybe this **note** of yours belongs somewhere else.

Comment: For the specific question asked here the advantage is indeed trivial - one round-trip to the server vs two. For other applications that might make use of the solutions presented here the savings of a round-trip to the server for each field renamed could be of interest.